# Нужно ли тире, если пропущен член предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

**«Аэрофлот» предоставил два самолета. Один — для бойцов.**

Нужно ли тире?

Answer (score 1):

Ну конечно нужно. Вы и причину назвали, пропущено слово. А почему сомнения-то возникли?!

Comment: да сама не знаю)) Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

*«Аэрофлот» предоставил два самолета. Один* [предоставил; был предоставлен] *для бойцов.*

Предложение *"Один — для бойцов"* является неполным, в нем отсутствует сказуемое. Этот пропуск связан с тем, что сказуемое названо ранее, в предыдущем предложении.

**Правило**: при наличии паузы на месте отсутствующего главного или второстепенного члена в неполных предложениях ставится тире. Оно называется *эллиптическим*.
[**Тире в неполном предложении**](http://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37405.php)

*«Аэрофлот» предоставил два самолета. **Один — для бойцов.***

*Мне все послушно, я же — ничему.*
(А.С. Пушкин)

*Огонь огнем встречают,

Беду — бедой и хворью лечат хворь...*
(В.Шекспир. Ромео и Джульетта. Пер. Б.Л. Пастернака)